# Mono restart console application

Tags: linux, mono, restart, raspberry-pi

I have written a console application in mono for linux.

i have to start it with

"sudo mono app.exe"

Is there some posibility to restart the app when something happens.

For examlpe I run this app on the raspberry Pi, and when the app
detects some voltage on a special IO pin the app should restart automatically.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch a new application instance using methods in the Process class and later exit.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use cmd.exe to execute the script. In this blog post the author asks cmd to wait for a while, and then delete the executable,

http://blog.pedroliska.com/2010/05/20/c-self-destruct-windows-app/

You can use the same trick to restart the executable if on Windows.

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();

// The delay is just making sure the exe to delete is done
// running.
var delayPings = 2;
var exeName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("(ping -n " + delayPings + " 127.0.0.1) && (CALL " + exeName + ")");
```

Now for Linux, you just need to use `bash` (or another Shell) to replace `cmd` and also modify the command passed to it.